Is this possible to generate 10 MFA backup recovery codes for user to login like in github?
Is this possible to invoke apex to programmatically generate MFA 10 MFA backup  Verification codes like it is implemented in Github?
Currently Admin can generate a code for the user but it will be limited in time and admin has to perform an action to generate it and then send it to the user.
Instead, can we implement in Salesforce the same what is implemented in Github?
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/configuring-two-factor-authentication-recovery-methods#generating-a-new-set-of-recovery-codes

The reason why customer needs this is that they have a limited number of admin and unlimited number of external users who might lose access to their MFA second factor and this would be unmanageable for them to manually generate recovery code for every single user affected by the loss of second factor.

Internal or external users (license type) ? What are you trying to accomplish, what's missing in out of the box implementation

client wants to provide functionality for external admins/moderators to unlink MFA for external users and generate MFA verification code. Is there any API for that @identigral ?

There's https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_2fa_apex_config.htm&type=5 but it has many caveats. You're better off with your own, custom code that does all of this.

I guess I would have to edit my question to make it clearer

You'd have to roll your own solution (the entire MFA process) if you want to provide a lower cost option (e.g. backup codes) to recover MFA authenticator. It's worth noting that backup codes in particular is a developer-friendly recovery method, it will not work for your average user. This problem isn't an easy one to solve at scale - it's a challenging tradeoff between security and ease of use/operational cost.
